# "о сайте" --> "о метке"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При просмотре вопросов по какой-то одной определённой метке, справа от списка вопросов есть блок, показывающий название метки и количество вопросов по этой метке. Также рядом с названием метки есть ссылка "о сайте", например:

[image: о сайте]

Однако ссылка ведёт на "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info", что по смыслу - информация о метке, и при нажатии, собственно это и получаем:

[image: о метке]

Т.е. по-моему "о сайте" нужно переименовать на "о метке".

Comment: Осторожнее с экранированием. В ссылке `#` интерпретировался, как `location.hash` и ссылка вела на список вопросов по [tag:c]. Упс.