# Некорректный перевод About в профиле пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Вероятно тут подразумевалось что-то типа "О пользователе":

[image: профиль на русском]

На английском в профиле написано "About"

[image: профиль на английском]

> Просьба проголосовать за [этот же вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369294/every-about-to-translate-should-have-its-own-source-string) т.к. надо чтобы сначала там внесли изменения, а потом уже у нас напишут корректный перевод
>
> -- *EzioMercer*

Comment: уже несколько таких вопросов было :)

Comment: @Grundy Правда? Я посмотрел последние темы, но что-то не нашёл ничего похожего. Давайте задубликатим тогда? Или вообще грохни - ты же модератор.

Comment: они не совсем дубликаты: [“о сайте” --> “о метке”](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2593/186999), , [На странице метки не сходятся термины](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8064/186999) [Участник - это не метка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8423/186999)

Comment: Уже оформлено [багом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369294/339911) на MSE.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, а там опять одна и та же строка в нескольких местах используется? Вроде кучу раз чинили уже?

Comment: @Grundy чинили один раз вроде (метка, компания). Теперь добавили новое место использования, а контекст новый (профиль) не добавили.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ок, напишешь ответ?

Comment: @Grundy когда контекст добавят и можно будет пофиксить, тогда и ответ можно будет написать. А сейчас-то о чём писать?

Comment: Сто лет назад об этом писал...

Comment: Я хочу продолжить быть меткой, мне нравится

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8423/178988

Comment: @nomnoms12 [tag:nomnoms12] с вами нет вопросов :o

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Жду Ваших вопросов

Comment: @nomnoms12 Сначала надо составить описание метки, а то фиг поймешь, что она значит

Comment: я так понимаю это еще не поправлено, потому что у меня на странице по прежнему написано "О Метке"?)

Comment: воз и ныне там, почти успел создать вопрос. этот попался в рекомендациях, далеко не в начале списка, правда

Comment: Почему так долго это исправляют?)

Comment: @EzioMercer потому, что это на функционал это не влияет, и не аффектит англоязычные сайты (которых подавляющее большинство).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А там проблема с тем что ключи для переводов одинаковые? Потому что обычно просто переводы у нас достаточно быстро решаются

Comment: @EzioMercer да. Об этом всё описано на [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369294/339911). Может конкурс ещё дополнительное внимание привлечет тех, кто реально может улучшить ситуацию.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Довольно щедрое вознаграждение!) Спасибо!

Comment: @EzioMercer просто оно уже пятое по счёту на том вопросе :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, но 400 не было до сих пор, максимум было 200 :)

Comment: @EzioMercer там каждый последующий должен быть больше, чем предыдущий. Иначе система не даёт начать конкурс. Исключение только для максимального в 500 реп.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Либо вы ошибаетесь либо правила изменились либо я что-то не так понимаю: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOr7V.png

Comment: @EzioMercer там ещё привязка к участнику есть, да. Т.е. Михаил теперь минимум 200 может предложить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А, всё понял, спасибо за разъяснение!)

Answer (score 4):

Добавили [отдельный контекст на участника](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386139/339911), теперь отображается так:

> [image: о себе]

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18843

Comment: А можно сделать разделение на то кто зашёл на страницу пофиля? Просто "Об участнике" - такое ощущение что о другом участнике, мне бы хотелось там видеть "О себе", а у других видеть "Об участнике". Если разделение не возможно, то как по мне "О себе" более подходящее

Comment: @EzioMercer о разделении надо просить на MSE. "О себе" для всех - можно попробовать, ждите новых сборок.

Comment: Я хотел сначала выяснить возможно ли это вприницпе?) На счёт "О себе" для всех - думаю стоит открыть вопрос на мете и все проголосуем за варианты, то что мне лично нравится, не значит сообществу тоже так больше нравится))

Comment: @EzioMercer всё возможно. Но все хотелки, требующие участия разрабов (а добавление логики "свой-чужой" к такому относится), идёт с большИм скрипом. "О себе" нормально, сам собирался поменять уже, так что нечего тут голосовать.

Comment: "большИм скрипом" - именно это меня и останавливает, т.к. скорее всего эта проверка должна будет быть везде (как мне кажется), потому вряд ли это сделают. На счёт "О себе" - почему я чутка сомневаюсь, потому что выше написано "Участник в течение ..." и снизу надпись "Об участнике" выглядит не сильно страшно. Ну если хотите/можете менять сами, то вас никто не остановит :)

Comment: @EzioMercer уже обновилось.