# Почему на Traducir требуется перевод для многих одинаковых фраз?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, traducir

Почему на Traducir требуется перевод для многих одинаковых фраз? Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: разный контекст, разные типы числительных

Comment: @Grundy числительные обычно задаются на целевом языке перевода. Зачем их целых девять на исходном английском-то?

Comment: @andreymal, имелись ввиду группы, один, несколько, много

Comment: @andreymal, для двух переменных в строке как раз 9 вариантов и выходит

Comment: @Grundy 9 вариантов в русском, а на английском всего 4 (а учитывая что строки тут идентифицируются по искусственным ключам, то строка должна быть вообще всего одна)

Comment: А впрочем ладно, заглянул в португальский Traducir - там таки 4 строки. Значит технически сделано всё верно, просто интерфейс у Traducir кривой)

Comment: @andreymal в какой части кривой интерфейс? Ну то есть он, конечно, много где кривой там :) Но в данном случае не очень понял проблему.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ если исходная строка одна, то значит и отображаться она должна одна, а не дублироваться девять раз. Дублироваться девять раз должны только поля для ввода фразы на целевом языке

Comment: @andreymal а как предлагается выйти на эти 9 полей для ввода строк? Собрать их всех в одном popup-окне? Сейчас эти окошки унифицированы: один вход (исходная строка), один выход (выходная строка). Если у вас есть идея как это улучшить, то было бы хорошо опубликовать эту идею как feature-request на MSE, чтобы не плодить тут обсуждение в комментах.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для строк, где есть числа, обычно используются несколько вариантов:

- one  // для чисел 1, 21, 31 ...
- few  // для чисел 2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 24, 32, 33, 34 ...
- many // для чисел 5-20, 25-30, 35-40 ...

Вариант указан в выпадашке конкретной строки, например:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если чисел в строке несколько, то кол-во возможных вариантов увеличивается. Для 2х - 9 строк, для 3х - 27 строк, для 4х - 81 строка ...

Есть предложение, чтобы [не использовать более 2 чисел в одной строке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911), иначе перевод становится настоящей пыткой.

Помимо чисел в строках, могут использоваться разные контексты, т.е. где строка должна применяться. Показательный пример, это строки [About](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=About%24):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контекст применимый к метке (tag):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О проблемах с переводом About было упомянуто на нашей Мете: [Некорректный перевод About в профиле пользователя](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11701/176217) и на MSE: [Every "about" to translate should have its own source string](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369294/339911)

Также рекомендую обратить внимание [сюда](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1136/176217) для получения дополнительной информации о переводе интерфейса ruSO.